# magentodockermagento241_redis_1 Cannot start service redis

Tags: magento2.4.1, pwa-studio, pwa-theme

[image]I have try to install PWASacndi them in my local server.
But when I run dc up -d --remove-orphans command.
Error is shown like below the screen short so can you please help me and please say me how to solve that error

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, port 6379 is already in use so docker can't able to run the container using the 6379 port. So first stop local Redis before you run the docker command.

you can check already running process details for port 6379 by the below command.

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 6379
```